# .net MVC5 Session["XYZ"] security with SSL

Tags: .net, security, session, ssl, asp.net-mvc-5

in .net If I have an object with an ID that I deal with at some point and save that object for a second in the session like so

```
Session["xyz"] = theobject;
```

Can the object then be accessed and / or manipulated by the client if the site only uses SSL?

I would like to put some commonly used objects there but if the client browsing this could manipulate or hijack the session it would be a security issue.